# How to use templates in AWS SES?

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

With Boto3 version in AWS Lambda, I've tried the following:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

ses_client = boto3.client('ses')
template = ses_client.get_template(TemplateName='abc')
```

But the `get_template()` API throws the exception:

> AttributeError: 'SES' object has no attribute 'get_template'

The API docs for [get_template()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.get_template)

Comment: I am also getting the same *exception*. I even tried with the latest ***boto3*** package. The same API is working fine in ***node.js***. Maybe there is an issue.

Comment: I’m using pystache